# Ruby ancestors chain. Find child class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have method `current_user`.

This method returns `#<User id: 8, ... >`

Also I have two inherited classes from `User`: `Trainer` and `Client`

I added methods to my `User.rb`:

```
def client?
  self.class.name == "Client"
end

def trainer?
  self.class.name == "Trainer"
end
```

But `current_user.client?` and `current_user.trainer?` always return false.

Why is this happening? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should probably check the `type` column in your methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `current_user.client?` and `current_user.trainer?` always returning `false`, this probably means that `current_user` always returns a `User` instance, rather than a `Trainer` or `Client` instance. And if `current_user` always returns a `User` instance, `self.class.name` will always be `"User"`, which will return false for `client?` and `trainer?`.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. I expect you're actually instantiating the User class. See if you can find where you are instantiating a User or are you retrieving it from the database in which case check out: http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations or a related Single Table Inheritance discussion.

```
class User
  def client?
    self.class.name == "Client"
  end

  def trainer?
    self.class.name == "Trainer"
  end

  def user?
    self.class.name == "User"
  end

end

class Trainer < User
end

class Client < User
end

puts Client.new.client?
puts Client.new.trainer?
puts Client.new.user?

puts Trainer.new.client?
puts Trainer.new.trainer?
puts Client.new.user?
```

output:

```
true
false
false
false
true
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have already answered the probably reasons why your code might fail. Let me just add that this is *terrible* OO code! An object should *never ever* need to check its own class! Never! Just let the method dispatcher do its job, that's what it's there for!

```
class Client < User
  def client?;  true  end
  def trainer?; false end
end

class Trainer < User
  def client?;  false end
  def trainer?; true  end
end
```